# How should I parse this data?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm currently importing some csv and parsing the data using python. One column in particular has different formats and I'm not exactly sure which approach I should use to parse the data.

The data in that column can have the following formats

```
5.00 LBS
5.00LBS
5.00lbs
5LBS
5 LBS
5 kg
```

or any other unit

What I would like to do is store the number in one variable and the unit in another so I can  later use them in my `Django` Model and create an object.

```
import csv
def import_measurements(request):
    path = 'measurements.csv'
    with open(path) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            # unit = row[0] string portion
            # weight =  row[0] number portion
            created = Measurements.objects.create(
                           unit=unit,
                           weight=weight
            )
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you show your code even extracting data from `csv` then we can help you ! the aim of SO in not give you answer , but help to solve the problems ! that you are faced !

Comment: I've asked for an approach not a solution. I can and would rather come up with the solution myself. I would just like information on possible techniques that can be used to do this efficiently and correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your value is composed of 2 parts: a number (decimal or not), and a unit (lbs or kg), separated by an optional space.

I would use a regex in the form:

```
(\d(?:\.\d{2})?)\s?((?:lbs)|(?:kg))
```

Using the `i` flag to ignore the case.

The first group would contain `5` or `5.00`, and the second, the unit. Lowercase the unit, and there you have it.

Left as an exercise to the reader the possibility to handle various decimal separators (`,` for example), and to support thousand separators.

A more relaxed but therefore less strict expression could be:

```
([0-9.]+)\s?(\w+)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regx:

```
>>> doc
'5.00 LBS\n5.00LBS\n5.00lbs\n5LBS\n5 LBS\n5 kg'
>>> re.findall('(\d+\.?\d*)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)',doc)
[('5.00', 'LBS'), ('5.00', 'LBS'), ('5.00', 'lbs'), ('5', 'LBS'), ('5', 'LBS'), ('5', 'kg')]
```